# How to assign BSON _Id to a cookie (Go, Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, cookies, go, bson

I was trying to create a go cookie. I want to assign Id from Mongodb to be stored in the Cookie. But while compiling I am getting an error as follows:-

"unknown http.Cookie field 'Id' in struct literal"

The following is my code:-

```
getUser := user.CheckDB()
expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)

//The Error is Caused by the Next Line
cookie := http.Cookie{Id: getUser[0].Id, Name: getUser[0].Email, Value: getUser[0].Password, Expires: expiration}
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)



func (this *User) CheckDB() []User {
    var results []User
    sess, db := GetDatabase()
    defer sess.Close()
    c := db.C("user")
    uname := &this.Email
    err := c.Find(bson.M{"email": *uname}).Sort("-id").All(&results)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Results All: ", results)
        return results
    }
}

type Cookie struct {
    Id         bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name       string
    Value      string
    Path       string
    Domain     string
    Expires    time.Time
    RawExpires string
    MaxAge     int
    Secure     bool
    HttpOnly   bool
    Raw        string
    Unparsed   []string
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `http.Cookie` and your `Cookie` type are not the same. A `http.Cookie` has no field `Id`.

Comment: @thwd What should I do? Can you please suggest me a solution. I need to store the Id in the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for this problem.

Cookie struct below:

```
type Cookie struct {    
    Name       string
    Value      string
    Path       string
    Domain     string
    Expires    time.Time
    RawExpires string
    MaxAge   int
    Secure   bool
    HttpOnly bool
    Raw      string
    Unparsed []string
}
```

Cookie Creation

```
 value := map[string]string{
        "id": cookieId,
    }
    if encoded, err := ckieHandler.Encode("session", value); err == nil {
        cookie := &http.Cookie{
        Name:  "session",
        Value: encoded,
        Path:  "/",
        }
        http.SetCookie(response, cookie)
    }
```

Cookie Call

```
if cookie, err := request.Cookie("session"); err == nil {
        cookieValue := make(map[string]string)
        if err = ckieHandler.Decode("session", cookie.Value, &cookieValue); err == nil {
            id = cookieValue["id"] // **Pass BSON ID here**
        }
    }
```

For more details [Click Here](https://mschoebel.info/2014/03/09/snippet-golang-webapp-login-logout/). This link helped me a lot. Hoping someone will find this answer useful.